# Filling animation + permanent mask in swift?

Tags: swift, animation, mask, fill

Something like this:

[image]

Or follow this link if you can:

https://www.lottiefiles.com/450-play-fill-loader

My case is simpler - I have a view with mask which consists of multiple rects and a linear fill. Mask is created in runtime (so I can't use lottie) but remains permanent, fill is animated (filling from right to left). But how to draw it?

Note: I tried to find a similar animation implementation but in most cases they just try to change the mask params while in my case mask is constant.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, you can add subview under your mask and change its width, something like that:

```
let fillingStartFrame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: view.frame.height)
let fillingEndFrame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.width)
let fillingView = UIView(frame: fillingStartFrame)
view.insertSubview(fillingView, belowSubview: YOUR_MASK)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    fillingView.frame = fillingEndFrame
}
```